# mysql not ordering using Order by using DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Using mysql on ubuntu

the following command is not ordering in descending order

```
mysql> select spo_id, count(spo_id) as "maxCount" from order_details GROUP BY spo_id ORDER BY "maxCount" DESC;
+--------+----------+
| spo_id | maxCount |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |        1 |
|      2 |        3 |
|      3 |        1 |
+--------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are ordering by a constant/string "maxCount" it would be akin to saying `ORDER BY 1 DESC` which is meaningless-ish.

Comment: @JNevill: `ORDER BY 1 DESC` is acceptable to most  DBMSs (not sure about MySQL). It means *order by the first column in the SELECT list*. In this specific case, `ORDER BY 2 DESC` would accomplish what the poster is intending.

Comment: @KenWhite Oh geez. Yes my bad. That is a bad example. `ORDER BY "somestring" desc` would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL allows string literals with double quotes. So when you order by "maxCount", you're in fact ordering by a string literal, which is just meaningless. Remove the quotes and it should work just fine:

```
MariaDB [db]> select spo_id, count(spo_id) as maxCount from order_details GROUP BY spo_id ORDER BY maxCount DESC;
+--------+----------+
| spo_id | maxCount |
+--------+----------+
|      2 |        3 |
|      3 |        1 |
|      1 |        1 |
+--------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```